# What species of bonsai is this?

Tags: identification, bonsai

I was given a bonsai as a gift. I’m trying to identify the species so I can give it the right care

[image: bonsai leaves]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Chinese elm  - its Latin name is *Ulmus parviflora*. It actually does well outdoors during milder months, but indoors needs a medium to bright daylight position.  It's semi deciduous but usually keeps most of its leaves during winter if it is content with its care. It prefers higher humidity, so mist spraying frequently helps it to remain healthy. Further info here https://www.allthingsbonsai.co.uk/bonsai-tree-care/chinese-elm-bonsai-tree-care-guide/